# What's the equivalent to Oracle Packages in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, package

I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL and I wonder if such a thing exists...

I saw some discussions, but nothing concrete..

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

No, there is no equivalent.

The only *remotely* similar thing would be to create one schema for each "package" and put all functions of one package into that schema. That way you have at least something like the namespace that packages give you.

This of course does not give you package private functions or package wide variables at all.

Comment: :-( too bad...Packages are really effective!

Comment: @Shvalb: what I do not like at all about packages is that you are forced to put the complete source code (of the implementation) into a single file. Which makes it a lot harder to work on a large package in a team. So we wind up extracting package functions into regular functions only to be able to manage the source code better...

Comment: Yeah, I could imagine that it would be a problem....I'm just not right with make many public functions that should have been private.

Answer (score 2):

As written before postgresql has no packages.

Example with namespace. It can be placed in single **sql** file.

Other methods can be added similarly.

```
--drop function if exists pack_exmpl.get_name(bigint);
--drop function if exists pack_exmpl.get_abbr(bigint);    
--drop schema if exists pack_exmpl;

drop schema if exists pack_exmpl cascade;
create schema pack_exmpl;

create or replace function pack_exmpl.get_name(p_id bigint)
returns varchar as $$
declare
  l_retval varchar;
begin
   select name into l_retval from example_table where id = p_id;
   return l_retval;
end;
$$ language plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

create or replace function pack_exmpl.get_abbr(p_id bigint)
returns varchar as $$
declare
  l_retval varchar;
begin
  select abbr into l_retval from example_table where id = p_id;
  return l_retval;
end;
$$ language plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would point out that the EnterpriseDB version of Postgres supports Oracle Packages.

https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/epas/latest/epas_compat_bip_guide/02_packages/01_package_components/

https://www.enterprisedb.com/products/edb-postgres-advanced-server-secure-ha-oracle-compatible

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32735766)